# Why is the support library version of SimpleCursorAdapter different from the framework version?

Tags: android, android-support-library, simplecursoradapter

I am using android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter, occasionally I see crashes raised in its bindView method, one typical example being:

```
at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:135)
at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getDropDownView(CursorAdapter.java:270)
at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:741)
at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:737)
at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:685)
at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:964)
at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$PopupDataSetObserver.onChanged(ListPopupWindow.java:1248)
at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.swapCursor(CursorAdapter.java:347)
at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:326)
at org.totschnig.myexpenses.activity.ExpenseEdit.onLoadFinished(ExpenseEdit.java:1189)
```

This seems to be an issue that has been addressed by the resolution of https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8840, but this resolution is missing from the support library's version of SimpleCursorAdapter. I am wondering if this is simply an omission or if there is some difference in the support library that prevents this fix from being applied?